# Get thrown "Generator: 0 records selected for fetching" when trying to crawl a small majority of websites using Nutch

Tags: regex, solr, web-crawler, nutch

I have a site that runs using moderngov.co.uk (you send them a template, which they then upload). I'm trying to crawl this site so it can indexed by Solr and searched through a drupal site. I can crawl the vast majority of websites out there, but for some reason I am unable to crawl this one: http://scambs.moderngov.co.uk/uuCoverPage.aspx?bcr=1

The specific error I get is this:

```
Injector: starting at 2013-10-17 13:32:47
Injector: crawlDb: X-X/crawldb
Injector: urlDir: urls/seed.txt
Injector: Converting injected urls to crawl db entries.
Injector: total number of urls rejected by filters: 1
Injector: total number of urls injected after normalization and filtering: 0
Injector: Merging injected urls into crawl db.
Injector: finished at 2013-10-17 13:32:50, elapsed: 00:00:02
Thu, Oct 17, 2013 1:32:50 PM : Iteration 1 of 2
Generating a new segment
Generator: starting at 2013-10-17 13:32:51
Generator: Selecting best-scoring urls due for fetch.
Generator: filtering: false
Generator: normalizing: true
Generator: topN: 50000
Generator: 0 records selected for fetching, exiting ...
```

I'm not sure if it's got something to do with the regex patterns Nutch uses to parse html, or if there's a redirect that's causing issues, or something else entirely. Below are a few of the nutch config files:

Here are the urlfilters: http://pastebin.com/ZqeZUJa1

sysinfo:
Windows 7 (64-bit)
Solr 3.6.2
Apache Nutch 1.7

If anyone has come across this problem before, or might know why this is happening, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373714/apache-nutch-not-adding-internal-links-in-a-web-page-to-fetchlist

Comment: Thanks nimeshjm, however I've tried removing the ? from the regex, changing it to a +.* and even removing all regex filters, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

I tried that seed url and I got this error:

```
Denied by robots.txt: http://scambs.moderngov.co.uk/uuCoverPage.aspx?bcr=1
```

Looking at the robots.txt file of that site:

```
# Disallow all webbot searching 
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

You have to set a specific user agent in Nutch and modify the website to accept crawling form your user agent.

The property to change in Nutch is in conf/nutch-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>http.agent.name</name>
  <value>nutch</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer nimeshjm. I'd already set http.agent.name to >nutch site<, but when I changed it to >nutch< the crawl progressed much further than usual, but still returned the "0 records selected...". Then after crawling again it regressed to the usual short terminal output and threw that same warning.

Comment: That's a good start, but you still have to change the robots.txt in http://scambs.moderngov.co.uk to allow Nutch to crawl it

Comment: Unfortunatly the site is also hosted by a third party, so I'm unable to change robots.txt, however I should be able to ignore it shouldn't I?

Comment: Not via config: https://nutch.apache.org/bot.html#Sysadmins%2Frobots.txt  
You can get the Nutch source and bypass the check for robots.txt but that is not good practice.

Comment: I found the block in Fetch(Entry).java that checks the robots.txt. I'm assuming if I comment this out and recompile, that should sort it out.

Comment: Yeah, that should the trick.  
I never tried it myself but it looks promising.  https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/tags/release-1.7/src/java/org/apache/nutch/fetcher/Fetcher.java?view=markup

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     <property> 
   <name>db.fetch.schedule.class</name> 
   <value>org.apache.nutch.crawl.AdaptiveFetchSchedule</value> 
  </property>

<property>
  <name>db.fetch.interval.default</name>
  <value>10</value>
  <description>The default number of seconds between re-fetches of a page (30 days).
  </description>
</property>
  <property>
  <name>db.fetch.interval.max</name>
          <!-- for now always re-fetch everything -->
  <value>100</value>
  <description>The maximum number of seconds between re-fetches of a page
  (less than one day). After this period every page in the db will be re-tried, no
   matter what is its status.
  </description>
</property>
```